# The only way to start server sides (back end) is running them with a command line like "npm start"?

Tags: npm, server

...is there like compiling the project and make it run to be autoexecutable?

Sorry for the general question. I have been doing little projects with server side and I find that always I need to write "npm start" or so to make the whole start working.

My doubt is, Do these projects need to be compiled somehow or it is just as is, a simple line runs the coded files and that works like a server side?

Also, should not a server side  able to run by itself (by definition) when the system restarts? So far, I needed to create bat files/start folder in windows to make then run in case of restart.

Answer (score 1):

According to [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html):

```
npm start

This runs an arbitrary command specified in the package’s "start" property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.
```

To start the server you have to start a process and that process is started by npm start. If processes are killed they cannot be brought back to life by themselves. If the process is killed (eg when you restart) you have to make sure a new process is automatically spawned. You can accomplish this in multiple ways. You could use services (for example systemctl in Debian). You could also use tools like Kubernetes which can automatically restart a container in case of a crash.

Another possbile solution to use something like [Respawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/respawn) which allows you to respawn a process if it crashes from NodeJS code. Of course, it can also be accomplished with plain NodeJS.

Comment: Thank you. My doubt was more general, not specific to npm, but in server side execution in general.